# Adding percentages to multiple counts in one SQL SELECT Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a SELECT statement similar to the one below which returns several counts in one query.

```
SELECT  invalidCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <...a...> WHERE <...b...>),
        unknownCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <...c...> WHERE <...d...>),
        totalCount   = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <...e...> WHERE <...f...>)
```

This works fine but I wanted to add two percentage columns to the SELECT:

```
invalidCount * 100 / totalCount AS PercentageInvalid, 
unknownCount * 100 / totalCount AS UnknownPercentage
```

How do I modify my SELECT statement to handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a subquery in the `from` clause:

```
select
    s.invalidCount,
    s.unknownCount,
    s.totalCount,
    invalidCount * 100 / s.totalCount as PercentageInvalid,
    unknownCount * 100 / s.totalCount as PercentageUnknown
from
    (select  invalidCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <...a...> WHERE <...b...>),
        unknownCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <...c...> WHERE <...d...>),
        totalCount       = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <...e...> WHERE <...f...>)) s
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT invalidCount, 
  unknownCount, 
  totalCount, 
  invalidCount * 100 / totalCount AS PercentageInvalid, 
  unknownCount * 100 / totalCount AS UnknownPercentage 
FROM 
    (
      SELECT  invalidCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <...a...> WHERE <...b...>),  
      unknownCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <...c...> WHERE <...d...>),     
      totalCount       = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <...e...> WHERE <...f...>)
    )
```

Comment: Don't forget to CAST(totalCount as float) - otherwise you're doing integer division...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different approach using the OVER clause that is very cool - very efficient.  Check out this example against AdventureWorks:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CardType 
        ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY CardType) AS TypeCount
        ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY 1) AS TotalCount
        ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY CardType) / CAST(COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY 1) AS float) AS TypePercent
FROM Sales.CreditCard
```

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely go with Mike's solution! Much more elegant and more efficient.

But I don't see any reason not to use GROUP BY here. That would make it even more elegant and more efficient. I would suggest getting rid of a redundant "COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY 1)", and sum the counts instead.

```
SELECT CardType 
       , COUNT(*) AS TypeCount
       , SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () AS TotalCount
       , COUNT(*) * 1.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () AS TypePercent
FROM Sales.CreditCard
GROUP BY CardType
```

Notes:

- "PARTITION BY 1" was redundant, so omitted.
- Taking SUM of CardType-Counts saves
  us from counting the whole table once
  again without partitioning.
- *1.0 is used instead of casting.
- Query not tested, but it should work..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  invalidCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <...a...> WHERE <...b...>),
        unknownCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <...c...> WHERE <...d...>),
        totalCount       = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <...e...> WHERE <...f...>)
INTO #tmp

SELECT invalidCount,
       unknownCount,
       totalCount,
       invalidCount * 100 / totalCount AS PercentageInvalid, 
       unknownCount * 100 / totalCount AS UnknownPercentage
FROM #tmp

DROP TABLE #tmp
```

Comment: is this faster than if you do "select invalidCount*100 (etc.) from (existing query)"

Comment: It am not sure witch is faster but you can always write both querys and run the and see witch is faster using SQL Profiler