# Multiple count functions in a SELECT query

Tags: mysql, optimization, count

I have a select query like this

```
select count(distinct id)*100/totalcount as freq, count (distinct id) from 
<few joins, conditions, gorup by here> .....
```

Will this result in 2 calculations of count under MySql 5.0? I can calculate the frequency in my appliation as well if this is a problem. I am aware of the solutions presented in [Adding percentages to multiple counts in one SQL SELECT Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306112/) but I just want to avoid nested queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select count(distinct id)*100/totalcount as freq, count (distinct id) from 
<few joins, conditions, gorup by here> .....
```

Yes, it will result in several evaluations.

Each recordset on `DISTINCT id` will be built separately for each function

Note that if not for `DISTINCT`, `MySQL` would use each record only once (though in multiple function calls).

Since `COUNT` is very cheap, function calls add almost nothing to overall query time.

You can benefit from rewriting your query as this:

```
SELECT  COUNT(id) * 100 / totalcount AS freq,
        COUNT(id)
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT id
        FROM    original_query
        ) q
```

BTW, why do you need both `GROUP BY` and `DISTINCT` in one query? Could you please post your original query as it is?